# If $a | b - 2c$ and $a | 2b + 3c$ then $a | b$ and $a | c$. true or false proof? Discrete maths

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, integers

If $a | b-2c$ then $b-2c = ak$ and if  $a|2b+3c$ then $2b+3c = al$ .
So I tried doing a direct proof and I get $c = \frac{al-2ak}{7}$ where $a$ and $k$ are integers. $b = \frac{2al+3ak}{7}$ . The question also states $a,b$ and $c$ are integers . 
I can't figure out if it's true or false help plz.

Comment: False. Take $ b = 46;\;c=8$ then $(46 - 2\times 8, 46 + 3\times 8)=(30,70)$ are multiple of $10$ while 46 is not and 8 either

Comment: Double check the statement, since it is true if  there is a sign error on some summand, e.g. for $\, b+2c\ \ $

Answer (score 6):

Your computations say that it's wrong. Try $a=7$, $b=5$ and $c=-1$.

Comment: Thank you alot. That works the statement is false. I was trying to find values of a , b and c for which statement if false but failed . Did u just randomly guess a =7 , b =5 , c = -1 . how did u find those values . I am new to discrete mathematics.

Comment: @Mahir Shahriar I just solved the system. $b-2c=7$ and $2b+3c=7$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $a|3b-6c$ and   $a|4b+6c  $ thus $a|7 b$. So if $7|a$ then you can't say $a|b$.

Comment: Its $4b+6c$${}$

Answer (score 0):

One more counter example:

Let a = 7; b= 13 ; c = 3.

b - 2c = 7; 2b + 3c = 35;

a| (b - 2c) ;  and a| (2b + 3c);

But: a does not divide b; and

a does not divide c.